# How to do questions of partial differentiation?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative, wave-equation

How may I show that any function of the form $z = f(x+at) + g(x+at)$ is a solution of the wave equation. 
$$
\frac{\partial^2 z}{\partial t^2 } = a^2 \frac{\partial^2 z}{\partial x^2 }
$$

How can I solve this question? Please help me to answer.

Comment: Do you mean $x = f(x+at) + g(x - at)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be shown directly like this.
Suppose:
$$
z = f(x+at) + g(x-at)
$$
Then the spatial derivatives are
$$
\partial_x z = f'(x+at) + g'(x-at)
$$
$$
\partial_{xx} z = f''(x+at) + g''(x-at)
$$
Thus we get the following using the temporal derivatives
\begin{align*}
\partial_t z 
&= f'(x+at)a - g'(x-at)a \\
\partial_{tt} z 
&= \partial_t a(f'(x+at) - g'(x-at)) \\
&= a(f''(x+at)a + g''(x-at)a) \\
&= a^2(f''(x+at) + g''(x-at)) \\
&= a^2 \partial_{xx} z
\end{align*}
Hence $z$ satisfies 
$$
\partial_{tt} z = a^2 \partial_{xx} z
$$
As the comments above note, the canonical solution is the one I've put here.
But 
$ z = f(x+at) + g(x+at) = \tilde{f}(x+at) $
is also a solution by simply taking $g\equiv 0$.